# ManualResetEvent in .Net 5

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-standard-2.0

I'm looking into migrating a .Net Framework solution to .Net 5, and the portability analyzer lists the following issue in a 3rd-party assembly:

[image]

I'm just curious to know why it reports this as not supported when the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=net-5.0) appears to show the `Set()` method of System.Threading.ManualResetEvent is present in .Net 5 (and Standard 2.0 for that matter).

Is there something that I'm not getting here? Or will the issue actually be something *inside* the Set() method, e.g. the code will be doing something that would fail under .Net 5?

Comment: I'm using `ManualResetEvent.Set()` with .net 5.0 and it works just fine - a bug in the portability analyser perhaps?

Comment: When I try this in a .net framework 4.8 console app using `ManualResetEvent.Set()` it shows as 100% compatible. I'm using Portability Analyzer 2.7.0.3

Comment: Check the constructor call, named events are not available until .NET 6.  I think it is a Unix problem.